# Perl - Concat 2 Files in specific move order

Tags: perl, file, concatenation, sequences

I have two textfiles with almost identical content, identical number of rows. Each has a header(row 1) followed by two sequences(seperated by \n), header again(row 4), two sequences, header again(row7), ...
What I am trying to do is write a new file C, which is getting the header and sequences from file A (rows 1..3) followed by two sequences from File B, next 3 lines from file A, next two sequences from file B. It would look something like this:

```
FILE C:
A1
A2
A3
B2
B3
A4
A5
A6
B5
B6
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
my $i = 0;
for my $j (0 .. $#FILE_A) {
    for (0 .. 2) {
        $FILE_C[$i] = $FILE_A[$j];
        $i++; $j++;
    }
    $i = $i + 2;
}

$i=3;
my $j=1;

for my $j (0 .. $#FILE_B) {
    for(0 .. 1) {
        $FILE_C[$i] = $FILE_B[$j];
        $i++; $j++;
    }
    $i = $i + 3;
    $j++;
}
```

It doesn't produce the right output, hard to tell which lines he confuses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
for my $j (0..$#FILE_A){
```

thinks that it's in charge of making `$j` take every value between `0` and `$#FILE_A`; but then you have lines like this:

```
$i++; $j++;
```

that modify `$j` without the `for`-loop managing it.

Since you have such a simple pattern, and so few lines per group, I think it's simpler to write something like this:

```
my $i = 0;
for (my $i = 0, $j = 0; $j < @FILE_A; $i += 5, $j += 3) {
    # copy header:
    $FILE_C[$i] = $FILE_A[$j];
    # copy sequences from A:
    $FILE_C[$i + 1] = $FILE_A[$j + 1];
    $FILE_C[$i + 2] = $FILE_A[$j + 2];
    # copy sequences from B:
    $FILE_C[$i + 3] = $FILE_B[$j + 1];
    $FILE_C[$i + 4] = $FILE_B[$j + 2];
}
```